# How to optimize loading 10+ full size images on a page dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, performance, web

[On my page](http://karan.github.io/griddit), I'm dynamically loading 10 images at once. Most of the times, these images are huge 3000px+ and I simply resize them. On loading more images (infinite scroll), the page becomes pretty unless because of memory consumption.

Is there a way to optimize images really fast? I was thinking of maybe using an API for image compression, but I don't think that would be the most efficient way. I'm trying that I don't have to implement a server (not that I can't, but I don't want to).

Any ideas?

Comment: Resizing the images before they show in the client may be the most efficient way.

Comment: Efficient meaning time wise. I thinking compressing images would take at least 1 sec each, right?

Comment: Guessing how long it would take isn't a very accurate way of solving problems. See what other suggestions you get. Efficiency is not just about time, your problem is memory. Loading the image on a server with a faster connection than the user has, reducing its size and dumping it to the browser MAY be faster than letting the client load the huge image.

Comment: You could allow the client to display the image then re-render it either server-side or in the client, but you're still then loading massive images per user, when you could be caching the reduced versions so that subsequent viewers do not wait for pre-processing or for the huge image to load.

Comment: Those images are simply impractically huge for web use. The only way to 'optimize' them for web use is to do that server side--*before* the browser requests them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is resizing the images on server. It can be done on the fly, with a "image proxy" like https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy or some SaaS.
And, to reduce the load on the server you could add a CDN, like CloudFlare (free) or CloudFront.

Comment: I didn't think of an image proxy. This helps.